# Laravel 9 Call to a member function storeAs() on string on image upload

Tags: php, laravel

The below function works in my `create` method and is a solution from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72493267/laravel-9-and-livewire-2-multiple-storeas-methods-throwing-call-to-a-member-fun) of mine. I cannot seem to get to work in my `update` method--a `Call to a member function storeAs() on string` error keeps persisting. The error screen highlights the `foreach` loop.

**edit.php**

```
public function updateTentry($id)
{
    $tentry = Tentry::find($id);

    $images = [
        'image_plant_general',
        'image_plant_closeup',
        'image_fruit_in_plant',
        'image_fruit_in_plant_closeup',
        'image_fruit_in_harvest_single',
        'image_fruit_in_harvest_group'
    ];

    $data = [
        'trial_id' => $this->trial->id,
        'pt_plant_vigor' => $this->pt_plant_vigor,
        'pt_plant_color' => $this->pt_plant_color,
        'pt_plant_growth' => $this->pt_plant_growth,
        ... 
        // more variables
    ];

    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $data[$image] = $this->{$image}?->storeAs($this->evaluation->id, $this->trial->id . '_' . $this->tentry->id . '_' . $image . '_' . Carbon::now()->toDateString() . '.' . $this->{$image}->getClientOriginalExtension(), 'trial-entry-photos');
    }

    $tentry->update($data);

    session()->flash('success', 'Tentry Updated Successfully');

    return redirect()->route('tentry.edit', [$this->evaluation->id, $this->trial->id, $tentry->id]);
}
```

Comment: Please can you show how/where the properties are defined e.g. `$this->image_plant_general`.

Comment: are you sending the request as multi part form data?

Answer (score 0):

The **store** and **storeAs** functions are available on **UploadedFile**.

`$request->file()` returns an instance of `IlluminateHttp\UploadedFile` on which `store` and `storeAs()` methods exists.

So you need to change the following

```php
foreach ($images as $image) {
        $data[$image] = $this->{$image}?->storeAs($this->evaluation->id, $this->trial->id . '_' . $this->tentry->id . '_' . $image . '_' . Carbon::now()->toDateString() . '.' . $this->{$image}->getClientOriginalExtension(), 'trial-entry-photos');
    }
```

to

```php
foreach ($images as $image) {
    if(request()->hasFile($image) && request()->file($image)->isValid()) {
        $uploadedFile = request()->file($image);
        $data[$image] = $uploadedFile->storeAs(
            /** path where the uploaded file is to be stored */
            $this->evaluation->id, 

            /** Filename by which the uploaded file must be stored */
            $this->trial->id . '_' . $this->tentry->id . '_' . $image . '_' . Carbon::now()->toDateString() . '.' . $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalExtension(),

            /** name of one of the disks defined in the config/filesystems.php */
            'trial-entry-photos');
    }
}
```